# Sql_text Data Missing When Querying Extended Event File Target Using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, extended-events

I set up an Extended Events session to capture SQL Server error events.

Below is the TSQL I used to create the XE session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ErrorCapture] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname
    ,sqlserver.database_id
    ,sqlserver.sql_text
    ,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([severity]>=(11)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'D:\ErrorCapture.xel')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Using SSMS, I am able to view all of the available event data, including sql_text.  However, when using TSQL to query the event file, data for the sql_text action shows up as NULL.  Below is the query used.  Any thoughts on why this might be?

```
with ErrorCaptureEventData as
(
  select convert(xml, event_data) as EventData
  from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'D:\ErrorCapture*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
) 
select EventData.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2(7)') as TimeStamp
       ,EventData.value('(event/data[@name="error_number"]/value)[1]', 'int') AS [Error_Number]
       ,EventData.value('(event/data[@name="message"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Error_Message]
       ,EventData.value('(event/data[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS SQL_Text
       ,EventData.value('(event/data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS SQL_Statement
       ,EventData.value('(event/data[@name="severity"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS Severity
       ,DB_NAME(EventData.value('(event/action[@name="database_id"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')) AS [DB_Name]
       ,EventData.value('(event/action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS [User_Name]
 from ErrorCaptureEventData
 order by timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're parsing the XML wrong. Since `sql_text` is an action, you need to do this:

`value('(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')`

Comment: Thanks, Erik!  That solved my issue.  Changed that select item as below:

Comment: EventData.value('(event/action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS SQL_Text